# Determining if this set constitutes a basis for the polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra

Does the set {$1+t, t+t^2, t^2+t^3, ..., t^{n-1} + t^n$} constitute a basis for $P_n(\mathbb{R}$)?

($P_n(\mathbb{R}$) is the set of all polynomials of at most degree $n$).

By theorem, I know that this set is a basis if and only if for every polynomial in $P_n(\mathbb{R}$), it can be written uniquely as a linear combination of the vectors in the set.

So I thought about a counterexample $t^4 + 2$. From what I can tell, you cannot write this as a linear combination of any vectors in the set. Therefore it is not a basis.

Is there a more formal way of doing this? Or did I do it correctly? Or is there any better approaches?

Comment: You need n+1 vectors to span that space and you only have n.

Comment: Because evidently I like to make things harder than they needed to be! It escaped my mind. But yes, 1 would work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have n vectors, and you have a vector space with a dimension of n+1.  So the answer is no.

Comment: Gotcha! Good point. :-) Would my approach be incorrect?

Comment: There is certainly nothing wrong with finding a counterexample. It’s just easier to do in this case to track the dimensions and find a counterexample. For an easier counterexample you just use one, the constant polynomial.